# C# add item to listbox from list

Tags: c#, list, listbox

When a shortcut is pressed, a value is added to the list and passed to the listbox to add an item. However, if `AddRange(RecentColors.ToArray()` is used, not only new list items are added, but they are added continuously. If a new value is added to a list value, is there a way to add only that new value to the listbox?

```
 private void mainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            RecentColors.Add(hexToRGB(hexcode.Text));
            for(int i = 0; i < RecentColors.Count; i++)
            {
                color_list.Items.AddRange(RecentColors.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

[Capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivEYW.png)

[Capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k26eP.png)

When i add one item, i can't change the format that is already added..

Comment: You don't need to loop. Comment `for(int i = 0; i < RecentColors.Count; i++)` and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you has RecentColors with all items and each key press you add all items in the listbox. Try adding one element in RecentColors and also in the listbox:

```
var item = hexToRGB(hexcode.Text);
RecentColors.Add(item);
color_list.Items.Add(item);
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, first we are going to create a class for ListBox and ComboBox items.

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public bool Rgb { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Text to show in ComboBox
        return this.Rgb ? "RGB" : "HTML";
    }
}

public class ListBoxItem
{
    public bool Rgb { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Text to show in ListBox
        return this.Rgb ?
            $"{this.Color.R},{this.Color.G},{this.Color.B}" :
            $"{this.Color.R:X2}{this.Color.G:X2}{this.Color.B:X2}";
    }
}
```

Each item in these controls will be an object of these classes. Add the items to the ComboBox:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Rgb = true });
this.comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Rgb = false });
```

When you need add items to ListBox:

```
this.listBox1.Items.Add(
    new ListBoxItem { Rgb = true, Color = Color.Red });
```

Now, when you change between RGB and HTML in the ComboBox, you get the selected ComboBox item to know when show colors in RGB or in HTML. Then, iterate all ListBox items and set the RGB with this value. In this form, ListBox items will draw text in that mode. The ListBox doesn't know that your items has changes: you must force to redraw the items.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = (ListBoxItem)this.listBox1.Items[i];
        item.Rgb = comboBoxItem.Rgb;

        // To force redraw
        listBox1.Items[i] = listBox1.Items[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what I'm trying to make is to change the HTML format to HTML format when clicking HTML in the combo box, and to change the listbox to RGB format when clicking RGB. If I add one by one, how do I change all the previously added items?

Comment: Then when I want to add more items Can I just follow that?

Comment: When you want add one element, simply do a single listbox1.Items.Add(...). This only add a single item. The others items remain in the list but it's not a problem because they can show the colors in RGB or HTML using the previous code.

Comment: Sorry i meant when i add more item in combobox can i jus tfollow that format?

Comment: Yes, you can add a simple string to a ComboBox but also an object of a class with all the properties that you need. When you use a class, the text of the item is the ToString method return. With the ListBox is the same.

Comment: I really appreciate to you!!